# Can't connect to db in Play, connection string in application.conf

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.2

I can't connect to db using this code in `application.conf`:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgres:my_db123_dev"
db.default.user=my_user
db.default.password=123
```

The error: `play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]`

I'm not specifying `localhost` in there because it should be it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be `postgresql`, not `postgres` in your `db.default.url`.

Also, while the stuff below might not matter completely, it's good best practice:

1. Change `db.default.url` to `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/my_db123_dev` (having localhost there is always good).
2. Put quotes around your username and password, because it's good form.